# MYSQL + PHP to display data from two rows as a single column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with data in a following format

```
region   gender  age_group  population 

Dallas    M        1          200  
Dallas    F        1          500 
NY        M        1          320 
NY        F        1          310 
Dallas    M        2          300 
Dallas    F        2          600 
NY        M        2          400 
NY        F        2          800
```

I'm looking for the best query  to output my data in the following format

```
region/age_group      1           2
Gender             M     F       M    F
Dallas             200   500    300  600
NY                 320   310    400  800
```

my query returns only the top colum and region. Not sure how to sub divide the top colum into genders as appearing above

```sql
SELECT distinct (region), a.group_one, b.group_two 
FROM city_populations c  
LEFT JOIN city_populations AS a ON a.age_group=1 AND c.age_group=a.age_group  
LEFT JOIN city_populations AS b ON b.age_group=2 AND c.age_group=a.age_group
```

Comment: i guess you dont know how to format a question here. Better you check-out the tips to format question here.

Comment: I am sorry my Friend if my words seems to be harsh to you but believe i just want to inform you that there is really nice stuff here which can help you in formatting question and answer. Please dont mind as my sole intention was to inform you.

Comment: @Rico: First thing you need to do is to post some relevant code.

Comment: @OptimusCrime please check my query on the question

Comment: You should show such table in presentation layer. SQL does not run on presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks @shiplu.mokadd.im , I understand that using php arrays its possible, but i dont know how to go about it.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It outputs exactly what you wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//First i fetched all data from database

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from test2")or die(mysql_error());
$regions = array();
$age_groups = array();
while($det = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if(!in_array($det['region'], $regions)){
        $regions[] = $det['region'];
    }
    if(!in_array($det['age_group'], $age_groups)){
        $age_groups[] = $det['age_group'];
    }
    $rows[] = $det;
}
```

//then processed in php to show as you wanted

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Age group</td>";
foreach($age_groups as $keyAG => $valueAG){
    echo "<td colspan='2'>$valueAG</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Gender</td>";
foreach($age_groups as $keyAG => $valueAG){
    echo "<td>M</td>";
    echo "<td>F</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
foreach($regions as $keyR => $valueR){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$valueR."</td>";
    foreach($age_groups as $keyAG => $valueAG){

        foreach($rows as $keyROWS => $valueROWS){
            if($valueROWS['region'] == $valueR && $valueROWS['age_group'] == $valueAG){
                if($valueROWS['gender'] == 'M'){
                    echo "<td>".$valueROWS['population']."</td>";
                }
                elseif($valueROWS['gender'] == 'F'){
                    echo "<td>".$valueROWS['population']."</td>";
                }
            }
        }
        $data[$valueR][$valueAG] = array($maleValue, $femaleValue);

    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Note: It is highly recommended to use mysqli_* instead of mysql.

Comment: @bhavick thanks. Works as a charm! im modifying it to display 0 in rows where there's no population. I've been working on this for over a week! Much appreciation